# Powershell Chart Axis Datatype issue

Tags: powershell

looking for some assistance.

When I draw a chart using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart
The Y axis is formatted in scientific notation - as supposed to decimal which I desire.
I have a simple dataset contained within a single $hashtable.

```
    # data source
       $datasource = @{London = 0.000000512; Berlin = 0.000000520; Madrid = 0.000000519; Rome = 0.000000518; Paris = 0.000000503}

    foreach ($h in $datasource.Keys) 
        {
        echo ( "${h} $([decimal]$datasource.Item($h))"  )
        $chart1.Series["Price"].Points.addxy( $h ,[decimal]$datasource.Item($h))   
        }
```

When the chart is produced the Y axis looks like so:

[Chart snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v5oL.jpg)

These values write to console in the correct format, how can I add them to the chart series as type Decimal/Prevent the series showing them in scientific notation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [custom numeric format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) for the Y-Axis like this:

```
$chartarea.AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "##.###############";
```

Here is more complete example:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms 
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization 
$chart1 = New-object System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart 

$chart1.Width = 400
$chart1.Height = 400

$chartarea = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea
$chartarea.AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "##.###############";
$chartarea.AxisY.Minimum = 0.0000005
$chartarea.AxisY.Maximum = 0.00000052

$chart1.ChartAreas.Add($chartarea) 

$chart1.Titles.Add("The Price") | Out-Null
$chart1.Series.Add("Price") | Out-Null 
$chart1.Series[0].ChartType = [System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType]::Line
$chart1.Series[0].YValueType = [System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType]::Double

# data source
$datasource = @{London = 0.000000512; Berlin = 0.000000520; Madrid = 0.000000519; Rome = 0.000000518; Paris = 0.000000503}

foreach ($h in $datasource.Keys) 
{
    echo ( "${h} $([decimal]$datasource.Item($h))"  )
    $chart1.Series["Price"].Points.addxy( $h ,[decimal]$datasource.Item($h))   
}

$chart1.Anchor = [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Bottom -bor `
    [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Left -bor `
    [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Right -bor `
    [System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles]::Top 

$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Width = 450
$form.Height = 450
$form.Controls.Add($chart1)
$form.ShowDialog()
```